# Update/Insert DE record on cloud page with parameters

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, cloudpage

I have a button as an image in an Email in MC. (below)

```
<td width="41"><a href="%%=RedirectTo(@link0)=%%" target="_blank"><img src="nps_0.jpg" width="41" alt="0" style="max-width:41px;height:auto;" class="survey-table"></a></td>
```

I have the following AMPscript in the email to redirect customers to a cloudpage & pass some url parameters.

```
%%[var @id, @link0 set @id=[id] set @link0=Concat("CloudpageURL?nps=0&campaign=Onboarding&id=",@id)]%%
```

This part works fine & I can see the parameters along with the url when the image is clicked.

What I also want to do is send these parameters to a DE. The cloud page has no SUBMIT button. Below is my code in the Cloud page but it isn't working.

```
%%[var @id, @campaign, @nps

set @id = RequestParameter('id')
set @campaign = RequestParameter('campaign')
set @nps = RequestParameter('nps')

InsertDE('NPS_test','campaign',@campaign,'nps',@nps,'id',@id)]%%
```

Answer (score 4):

The InsertDE function is only meant to be for Emails, for landing pages use [insertData](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/insertdata.htm) or [UpsertData](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/upsertdata.htm)

You'll need to set the appropriate Primary key in your DE to ensure unique records. With insertData if theres a PK violation the insert will fail and you'll get a error. With the UpsertData depending on your primary key only 1 row will be inserted/updated.

Comment: Thanks Noor. that seems to have worked however i am getting duplicated records for a single entry. I have added the @date = Now(1) to the mix.

Comment: You'll need to set the appropriate Primary key in your DE to ensure unique records. With insertData if theres a PK violation the insert will fail and you'll get a error. With the UpsertData depending on your primary key only 1 row will be inserted/updated