# Trying to set up tracking of URL parameters on an SFMC CloudPage - for traffic from FB ads; and write UTM parameter values into a DE

Tags: marketing-cloud

I am new to CloudPages, and have been trying to see if I can retrieve and record UTM parameters' values (in SFMC) - from URLs/visits from our FB ads.

I have found some examples of how to record CloudPages forms' values into an SFMC DE (https://medium.com/@saurabh.samirs/insert-data-into-data-extension-using-cloud-pages-and-ampscript-9d0f5ddd2342), or from SFMC email links/URLs ([Update/Insert DE record on cloud page with parameters](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/325908/update-insert-de-record-on-cloud-page-with-parameters)), but for URLs of visitors from other websites (FB ads in this case), I am not sure how to adjust it.

I have this code (before HTML, in a code snippet box) at the top of CloudPage:

```ampscript
%%[ 
var @campaign, @medium, @source, @p_utc
set @campaign = QueryParameter('utm_campaign')
set @medium = QueryParameter('utm_medium')
set @source = QueryParameter('utm_source')
set @p_utc = QueryParameter('p_utc')

InsertData(
    "CloudPage_Parameters_test",
     "campaign",@campaign,
     "medium",@medium,
     "p_utc",@p_utc
     )
]%%
```

But I'm afraid it gives a warning* when I try to publish the page, and if I publish it anyway, the link/page shows a `500 - Internal server error`.

Have you come across an AMPScript which may work for this kind of (traffic from another website) URL parameters' tracking?

And perhaps I am not putting it in the right place.

An example of a URL from a FB ad would be:
https://www.domain.com/promotions/book-online/info.php?p_language=en&utm_source=facebook&utm_medium=paid-social&utm_campaign=test_media&p_utc=CloudPageTest

P.S. we also have a PHP snippet before this AMPScript - to retreive the 'p_utc' parameter from the URL

```php
<!--?php
// Start browser session
session_start();
// Set the UTC if none set yet
if(empty($_SESSION['p_utc']) && !empty($_REQUEST['p_utc'])) {
 $_SESSION['p_utc'] = $_REQUEST['p_utc'];
}
?-->
```

---

*Error text (CloudPages):

> An error occurred while previewing this content.
> This can happen for many reasons, including incomplete or incorrect MC scripting (AMPscript, SSJS or GTL) or missing subscriber context.
> Click Cancel to review your code or Publish to push the updated content live.

Comment: You can't run PHP in a Cloud Page. The only server-side languages supported are AMPScript and Server-Side JavaScript (SSJS). If you ditch the PHP you'll probably find the page works - I can't see anything immediately wrong with your AMPScript

Comment: that, and I would maybe add an "IF NOT EMPTY" bit around those vars that map to required fields in your DE. Your insert will break if a "required" value in the DE does not come in as parameter, and also output 500.

Comment: Oh I see, thank you! I removed the PHP part, but I am afraid still getting an error. I am just worried it was needed to populate the href link with the p_utc parameters (= Campaign name) of the 2 buttons/CTAs on this page (i.e.: href="https://www.domain.com/promotions/book-online/info.php?p_language=en&utm_source=@source&utm_medium=@medium&utm_campaign=@campaign&p_utc=CloudPageTest" ) - which should transfer this information to Tableau and GA (I hope). I will try to rewrite it in SSJS.

I do not have required fields in the target DE (but will try to add the "IF NOT EMPTY" clause, thanks!

Comment: P.S. and I put AMPScript in an HTML block (not a Code Snippet block), as I saw somewhere that this is how it is done.. And hid it with: <!--==  and ==--> (it used to be visible).

Comment: P.P.P.S. I realized, when I remove the 2nd part of AMPScript* - it works! (or at least I can publish the Cloud Page without an error). So the problem seems to be with the InsertData() part.. Ok. (will make sure IF EMPTY clause is there, although no required/non nullable fields in the target DE).

*
InsertData(
    "CloudPage_Parameters_test",
     "campaign",@campaign,
     "medium",@medium,
     "p_utc",@p_utc
     )

Comment: It may have to be smth more like this (the InsertData() part): https://ampscript.guide/insertdata/

Comment: @JarrettBush Thank you very much! I just wanted to mention, would this PHP be "read as" SSJS, maybe? Could it work? Just wondering, if this may be acceptable: 

<script runat="server"
        type="text/javascript">
  }
Catch (err){Write("Error:"+Stringify(err));
}
</script>

<!--?php
// Start browser session
session_start();
// Set the UTC if none set yet
if(empty($_SESSION['p_utc']) && !empty($_REQUEST['p_utc'])) {
 $_SESSION['p_utc'] = $_REQUEST['p_utc'];
}
?-->

Comment: @JarrettBush Sorry, I forgot to include a top part of this code (before the AMPScript part), I understand it is important:) 

<script runat="server" type="text/javascript">
Platform.Load("core","1");
  try{
</script>


<!--== 
%%[ 
..

Comment: @JarrettBush oh gosh, this works! (i.e. I can publish it..) I will see then if it writes UTM parameters in the DE. But exciting) Thanks so much.


* *after the QueryParameter() part, and after the AMPScript block closing bracket* *

<script runat="server">
    var rows = Platform.Function.InsertData("CloudPage_Parameters_test",
 ["campaign","medium","source","utc"],
 [@displayCamaign,@displayMedium,@displaySource,@displayUtc]);
</script>

Comment: I have had some progress (but still does not work, I'm afraid - i.e. does not write these values into my little DE):

1st part (AMPScript):

%%[ 
var @ campaign, @ medium, @ source, @ utc

set @ campaign = QueryParameter('utm_campaign')
set @ medium = QueryParameter('utm_medium')
set @ source = QueryParameter('utm_source')
set @ utc =    QueryParameter('p_utc')
  
]%%

Comment: P.S. 2nd part of the code, SSJS (did not fit in 1st comment):


<script runat="server" type="text/javascript">
Platform.Load("core","1");
  
set campaign = Variable.GetValue("@campaign");
set medium = Variable.GetValue("@medium");
set source = Variable.GetValue("@source");
set utc = Variable.GetValue("@utc");
  
var deName = 'CloudPage_Parameters_test'; 
var insertColumnArr = ['campaign','medium','source','utc']; 
var insertColumnValueArr = [campaign,medium,source,utc]; 
var insertedRowCount = Platform.Function.InsertData(deName, insertColumnArr, insertColumnValueArr);
</script>